# not getting the element in web service response for which value in "null"

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I am using the apache-cxf for webservice, the response generated does not contain the element(say of type java.lang.String) for which value is null. 
following is the xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="venueDetails">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="contactDetails" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="date" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description1" type="xs:string" nillable = "true"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description2" type="xs:string" nillable = "true"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="placePicture" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="time" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am expecting the element "description1" and "description2" in `SOAP` response even if these contain null value. But `SOAP` response does not contain these tags I i put null for them. 
Please let me know where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description1" type="xs:string" nillable = "true"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description2" type="xs:string" nillable = "true"/>
```

Try using this:

```
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description2" type="xs:string"/>
```

> Element that is nillable, meaning that the element CAN BE EMPTY
>   without causing a validation error

Take a look [here](http://java.boot.by/wsd-guide/ch02.html). You are already defining `minOccurs="0"` so do not need `nillable="true"`.